# Countdown Timer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, countdowntimer

Hi everyone I'm building a countdown timer for my site but I'm having a problem when adding the code a new countdown timer is getting created every second, I think it's because I'm injecting my html inside the setInterval function, I'm sure to fix this issue if anyone can help please.

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2023 15:37:25").getTime();

function makeMeTwoDigits(n){
    return (n < 10 ? "0" : "") + n;
}

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  const countdownHTML = 
 `<div class="countdown-main-container">
                <span class="sale-text">SALE ENDS</span>
                <div class="countdown-container">
                    <div class="countdown-date">${makeMeTwoDigits(days)} :</div>  
                    <div class="countdown-text">Days</div>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-container">
                    <div class="countdown-date">${makeMeTwoDigits(hours)} :</div>
                    <div class="countdown-text">Hours</div>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-container">
                    <div class="countdown-date">${makeMeTwoDigits(minutes)} :</div> 
                    <div class="countdown-text">Min</div>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-container">
                <div class="countdown-date">${makeMeTwoDigits(seconds)}</div>
                <div class="countdown-text">Secs</div>
            </div>
    </div>`;
    
    const countdownContent = document.querySelector('.col-sm-6');
    const newHTML = document.createElement('div');
    newHTML.setAttribute('id', 'randb-countdownSale');
    newHTML.innerHTML = countdownHTML;
    countdownContent.prepend(newHTML); 

}, 1000);


jQuery('.ib-text').remove();
document.querySelector('.info-bar').style.height = "52px";
document.querySelector('.oc-panel').style.paddingTop = "10px";

const coutdownStyle = `<style branchname="countdownSale">
.countdown-main-container {
   flex-direction: row; 
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   gap: 10px;
}
.countdown-container {
    display: flex; 
    justify-items: center; 
    align-items: center; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.sale-text {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.countdown-date {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
.countdown-text {
    color:#fff;
}
#colon {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
</style>
`;

jQuery("header").append(coutdownStyle);
```

I tried removing my html from inside the setInterval function but my code then spot working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you used `prepend`, and I assume that you want to replace the content.

Try instead

```js
countdownContent.innerHTML = "";
countdownContent.appendChild(newHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it's now working as it should :)